# Vertical Marquee JLabel in java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, marquee

I need to construct a marquee in java application. I thought that a JLabel is a good control to work with. I have done something with horizontal marquee label but making it vertical isn't so easy for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a JPanel with a JLabel inside to marque using the class below

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MarqeuePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
    private boolean IsStoped = false;
    private JLabel label;
    public MarqeuePanel(Dimension d,Point p,String text)
    {
        super();
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setText(text);
        add(label);
        setSize(d);
        setOpaque(false);
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        label.setLocation(0,this.getSize().height);
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        //Marqueue
        label.setLocation(0,this.getSize().height);
        while(!IsStoped)
        {
            if(label.getLocation().y < -label.getSize().height)
            {
                label.setLocation(0,this.getSize().height);
            }
            else
            {
                int x = 0;
                int y = label.getLocation().y - 1;
                label.setLocation(x,y);
            }
            try{Thread.sleep(30);}catch(Exception exc){}
        }
    }

    public void StopMarque()
    {
        IsStoped = true;
    }
}
```

Just careful if you need New Lines ,you can use  tag's

Comment: not, never use Thread.sleep(int) in Swing code because block EDT, this code is wrong, for that is there javax.swing.Timer

Comment: @mKorbel this code is executing on a separate Thread, so it doesn't block the EDT. However the suggestion to use a Swing Timer is still the better solution since the code will execute on the EDT which is want you want to happen since the label location is being changed.

Comment: @camickr I know about that, but I remember that I had question (old.forums.sun) about How to Shake with JButton, result was ... since works correctly with Thread.sleep(int) rather than implements `javax.swing.Timer` for that, because works correctly only for one JComponent on the EDT, if is there two or more JComponents then GUI simple freeze

Answer (score 3):

Try http://www.jidesoft.com/blog/2009/06/18/introduce-marqueepane-component-to-open-source-jide-common-layer/

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/ is horizontal only but might be adaptable to vertical as well)